# Multi-class AUC for GridSearchCV and RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: scikit-learn, auc, multiclass-classification

I'm using `GridSearchCV` and `RandomizedSearchCV`. I have a multi-class setting with 4 classes and an imbalanced dataset. Currently, I'm using `f1_micro` as the scoring function. Now I would like to use instead micro averaging of AUC. Is there a possibility to use such a multi class AUC for `GridSearchCV` and `RandomizedSearchCV`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you have to create scorer function and fill argument with `functools.partial`, see [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/73743/92015).